# Como saber si el usuario ha introducido valores

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una practica del grado donde el usuario introduce cuantos dados quiere lanzar y cuantas caras tiene ese dado.

El metodo funciona, ahora estoy trabajando en las excepciones (Controlar que no sea menor que 0, que no este vacio) y estoy teniendo problemas con este ultimo.
Son dos Edit Text, uno llamado **etcarasdeldado** y otro llamado **dadosalanzar**.

*etcarasdeldado* que es un Edit Text lo paso a un String llamado **value** y despues lo transformo a un integer llamado **carasdeldado**

*etdadosalanzar* que es un Edit Text lo paso a un String llamado **value1** y despues lo transformo a un integer llamado **dadosalanzar**

Una vez son Integer, hago la operación matematica y un TextView lo imprime.

```html
public void lanzardados(View view) {
        String value = etcarasdeldado.getText().toString();
        int carasdeldado = Integer.parseInt(value);

        String value1 = etdadosalanzar.getText().toString();
        int dadosalanzar = Integer.parseInt(value1);

        int resultado = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();

        try {
            if (carasdeldado <= 0 && dadosalanzar <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "El dado debe de tener como minimo dos caras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                if (//carasdeldado es un valor nulo && dadosalanzar es un valor nulo) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Debe de introducir algo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dadosalanzar; i++) {
                        resultado = resultado + (rand.nextInt(carasdeldado) + 1);
                    }
                    etfinal.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sys error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Bien , la excepcion para que sea menor que 0 esta controlada. El problema viene cuando quiero controlar que no lo deje vacio.
He probado con que la longitud de **carasdeldado** y **dadosalanzar** no sea 0, que **value** y **value1** con el .isEmpty(), pero todo me da error y la aplicación se me cierra.


¿Que se os ocurre que podria hacer? Un saludo de antemano y muchas gracias :)

**EDIT:**
Al final me daba error algo de un int. Lo que hice fue

-Primero Revisar que el String no este vacio

-Una vez que lo haya revisado, lo transformo a Int

-Ahora revisa que el valor de Int no sea menor o igual que 0

```
public void lanzardados(View view) {
    String value = etcarasdeldado.getText().toString();
    String value1 = etdadosalanzar.getText().toString();
    int resultado = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();

    try { if(value.isEmpty() && value1.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe de introducir algo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            int dadosalanzar = Integer.parseInt(value1);
            int carasdeldado = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (carasdeldado <= 0 && dadosalanzar <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "El dado debe de tener como minimo dos caras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            for (int i = 0; i < dadosalanzar; i++) {
                resultado = resultado + (rand.nextInt(carasdeldado) + 1);
            }
            etfinal.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sys error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: copia y pega tu código ;) es mas fácil que pasar una imagen y ayuda a los miembros de la comunidad a copilar el código, y así poder brindarte una ayuda

Comment: @Dramaturgo Muchas gracias por el comentario, acabo de editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para un null esto funciona:

```
 if (carasdelgado == null && dadosalanzar == null) 
    {
    // acción a realizar
    }
```

Pero como son tipo Int por haber convertido previamente el contenido recogido del Edit Text es posible que el resultado de la conversión sea el que crea los valores null.
También considera que puede que sea uno de los dos valores null y el otro no, con lo que habría que hacer las condiciones adecuadamente. Comprobar el valor de forma separada o bien usando el operador lógico ||.

Con la siguiente forma compruebas el valor como String de cada una de las variables:

```
if (value1 == null || value1.Lenght == 0 ||
value2 == null || value2.Lenght == 0)
{
//mensaje
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar los EditText para saber si tiene o no valor con esta comparación:

```
    String value = etcarasdeldado.getText().toString();

    if(value.trim().equals("")){
       //vacio
    }
```

pero además **es importante validar si el `EditText` tiene un valor que en verdad sea numerico, por lo tanto te sugiero validarlo para evitar errores en tu programa**, en caso de no ser numerico puedes definir como default el valor 0.

Usa el siguiente método:

```
  public static int validaValor(String valor) {
        int i = 0; //valor default
        try {
            i = Integer.parseFloat(valor);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
        }
        return i;
    }
```

y llama la validación de esta forma

```
...
...
String value = etcarasdeldado.getText().toString().trim();
int carasdeldado = validaValor(value);

String value1 = etdadosalanzar.getText().toString();
int dadosalanzar = validaValor(value1);

...
...
```